# Where to place logic specifically for VM and Service

Tags: c#, wpf, mvvm, mef

So I've refactored alot of my code so that it abides by the MVVM architecture. I'm using MEF and I'm using Caliburn Micro but I have a dilemma/question.

My ObjViewModel has some properties such as "IsAddObjToggleChecked" etc, and there is some logic that requires a check on this property, i.e. if this property is checked do some business logic. Now I don't want to have this logic in my viewmodel where it currently is because the viewmodel is 800 lines and has "business logic" - I have my ObjService which injects itself into my viewmodel and that contains an observable collection of Obj, where Obj is my Data Model.

Question is, where can I put this business logic? The data model wouldn't make sense for it to be in there as the business logic is working with an observable collection of data models. I was thinking to place it in my ObjService class, but then how can I have the business logic which contains a property of the viewmodel in there? Pass a parameter into the service? Does this then not create tight coupling?

Then I thought of just using a completely separate singleton class like an ObjHelper class.... to do the logic it needs to, but if we pass in the properties used in these helper functions/business logic, how will the viewmodel know they've been changed?

So i'm in a pickle as to where this should all go..

Comment: When you have a large class and it has some bit of functionality could be broken out then the usual approach is to create a new class and inject that. When there are many classes like this it's common to inject a container class of some sort which itself has these classes injected. There are of course variations like the factory pattern or a bridging object like a mediator.

Comment: Hey Andy. Question is what would this class be? It needs to be able to reference/modify a couple of the viewmodel's properties as mentioned above, but it equally will be a singleton/service that other viewmodels could access. I would have put this all in the ObjService if it wasn't for the few viewmodel's properties that are contained in that code, and I'm not sure how they should be separated out, or if they should just be passed in as parameters...

Comment: It depends. Which means your question is quite broad. If you want it to be a singleton then you need to pass in those variables to whatever method you're calling. Then if you need properties to change you set them in the calling vm.  If those properties are extensive then it could take an instance of viewmodel as a parameter but then what it does becomes somewhat obscured.

Comment: Hmm yes... perhaps I could create a service that implements the original service, and in the service I could have a bool property like "CanAddObj", then perhaps I can somehow have some kind of two-way binding? I.e. if the `IsAddObjToggleChecked` bool is set to true, then the `CanAddObj` bool in the service gets set to true... though I'm not sure how to do this... the service should not know about anything outside of it except the datamodel.